# Detect Project Loom technology as missing or present JVM at runtime

Tags: java, fibers, project-loom

[Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) is now available in [special early-release builds](https://jdk.java.net/loom/) of Java 16.

If I were to run my Loom-based app on a Java implementation lacking in the Project Loom technology, is there a way to detect that gracefully early in my app launching?

I want to write code something like this:

```java
if( projectLoomIsPresent() )
{
    … proceed …
}
else
{
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Project Loom technology not present." ) ;
}
```

How might I implement a `projectLoomIsPresent()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

```
return System.getProperty("java.version").contains("loom");
```

Method 2:

```
try {
    Thread.class.getDeclaredMethod("startVirtualThread", Runnable.class);
    return true;
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's faster if you don't have to catch an exception. In my original answer, I was using Class.forName and catching an exception, but I refactored it to avoid that.

Comment: @DavidConrad Once Project Loom is released, it will be enough to check the Java version. Regarding performance, note that `Class#getDeclaredMethods()` creates a copy of the array, while `Class#getDeclaredMethod()` does not. In my benchmark the difference is negligible, if any.

Comment: If you care about performance - cache the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for features not present before Project Loom:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static boolean projectLoomIsPresent() {
    return Arrays.stream(Thread.class.getClasses())
        .map(Class::getSimpleName)
        .anyMatch(name -> name.equals("Builder"));
}
```

There's no need to possibly catch an exception:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public static boolean projectLoomIsPresent() {
    return Arrays.stream(Thread.class.getDeclaredMethods())
        .map(Method::getName)
        .anyMatch(name -> name.equals("startVirtualThread"));
}
```